# strcmp doesn't work with Qt

Tags: c++, string, qt

I am working with Qt and C++. While using the C++ `std::strcmp` function, the compiler shows some error regarding member function is not constant. I use this code

```
std::string password;
std::string const ashish="ashish";
password=ui->label_password->text().toStdString(); //i use it to take input from line edit bottom
int a=strcmp(password,ashish);
if (a=0)
  ui->label_3->setText(QString::fromStdString("sucess"));
```

`Then it shows the following error

> ```
> error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
> int a=strcmp(password,ashish);
> ```

can you please suggest me the solution of this problem or some other better option to compare string(not QString)

Comment: Why do you expect a function that takes `const char*` to accept an `std::string`? You can extract the `const char*` using the `c_str()` function from your `std::string` and then pass it to the `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `strcmp` takes `const char*` as parameter and you provided `std::string`, it won't work. You can use `c_str` to convert `std::string` to `char*` at first, then pass it to the `strcmp`.

Here is the [Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) for c_str.

Also, you can use std::string::compare,

Here is another [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The inputs to `strcmp` need to be `char const*`, i.e. C strings. You cannot use `std::string` as arguments to `strcmp`. When at least of the variables is a `std::string`, you can simply use `operator==`.

Replace the lines

```
int a=strcmp(password,ashish);
if (a=0)
  ui->label_3->setText(QString::fromStdString("sucess"));
```

with

```
if ( password == ashish )
  ui->label_3->setText(QString::fromStdString("sucess"));
```

---

You may also skip the conversions to `std::string` altogether and use `QString` directly.

```
QString ashish = "ashish";
QString password = ui->label_password->text();
if ( password == ashish )
  ui->label_3->setText("sucess");
```

Comment: But i need to  work with the string because i am using the file input. is ti possible to work with string rather then Qstring (sorry for bad English, i will improve it in future )

Comment: @ashishgm, of course you can. If you use Qt for your user interface, youl'll have to deal with converting `QString` to `std::string` and vice-versa.

Comment: i know how to convert Qstring into string.but don't know reverse.how can i convert string into the Qstring ?

Comment: @ashishgm, you already have the function for that. `QString::fromStdString()` constructs a `QString` from a `std::string`.